# How to show hostname in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently work on a hacker news clone to learn rails. But when I want show the host name, rails shows whole url in the index action. for example whenever I want put 
<%= link.url %> it gives "www.somewebsite.com/someurl". But I just want show "www.somewebsite.com" in the index action. I don't know how to do it.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, use the request object like below:

```
<%= request.host %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very robust solution would be creating an instance of the Ruby URI class and then extract the host, as in

URI::Parser.new.parse('https://teowaki.com/path').host

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
request.host
```

or

```
request.host_with_port
```

If you also want the port information

You can also use

```
request.domain
```

Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-host)